# Running time and standard deviation of Marsaglia and Bray's Polar Method

Tags: algorithms, random-variables

I have some trouble calculating the standard Deviation and the mean running time of the polar method by Marsaglia and Bray. More specifically the repeat portion of the algorithm. In this case the $U_k$ values are independent uniform variables so they Change with each iteration.

The Basic algorithm goes as follows:

$$repeat:$$
   $$V_1 = 2*U_1 - 1 ;U_1 \in (0,1) ;V_1 \in (-1,1)$$
   $$V_2 = 2*U_2 - 1 ;U_2 \in (0,1) ;V_2 \in (-1,1)$$

$$S = V_1^2 + V_2^2 $$

$$until(S<1)$$
   $$X_1 = V_1 * \sqrt(-2lnS/S) $$
   $$X_2 = V_2 * \sqrt(-2lnS/S) $$

I would really appreciate some starting points. Thanks in advance.

In particular, I seek the running time of the repeat method and the standard deviation of that running time.

From what i can see the best case would be: $O(1)$ the worst case $O(n)$.

Comment: There does not seem to be any point to the loop as nothing changes from one iteration to the next. Is it perhaps that $U_1=2U_1$? Or $V_1=2V_1$?

Comment: Yeah sry. The V-Values are decremented by each step

Comment: Then somewhere you should mention that the $U_i$ are uniformly distributed random variables that get a new value in each iteration. So essentially the first loop computes a random point uniformly from the unit disk which is then rescaled to the point $X$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For every single loop, the probability to succeed is $p=\frac{\pi}{4}$. The probability to succeed after $k$ iterations is $(1-p)^{k-1}p$, as it requires $k-1$ fails before that. The expectation is thus
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty k(1-p)^{k-1}p
$$
which is related to the geometric series. The variance requires to also compute
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty k^2(1-p)^{k-1}p
$$
You might be faster by computing the generating function of the moments
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty e^{-kt}(1-p)^{k-1}p
$$

Comment: Thanks. From that i get that the average times of runs would be 1.27 times, which seems right.